# hide the MUI datatable until file upload

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to hide the data table until my file uploaded. as of now, I'm getting a blank table, but I want to hide the table till I upload my file.

```
var selectedList = {};
const columns = [
 {
  name: "id",
  label: "Select",
  options: {
    filter: true,
   display: Hidden
}
},
{
 name: "question",
 label: "Questions",
 options: {
   filter: true,
  sort: false
}
},
{
name: "answer",
label: "Answers",
options: {
  filter: true,
  sort: false
}
}
];
const options = {
filterType: "checkbox",
selectableRows: false,
selectableRowsOnClick: true,
customToolbarSelect: () => {},
onRowsSelect: (rowData, rowState) => {
selectedList = rowState;
}
};
```

and in my render statement i am returning this:

```
     <div>
        <div className="peers fxw-nw pos-r">
          <div className="" id="main-window-scroll">
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.getMuiTheme()}>
              <MUIDataTable
                title={"FAQs Data List"}
                data={this.state.faqList}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
                // onRowClick={this.handleRowSelection}
              />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            {/* {this.loadDataTable()} */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How can i hide my table by default, and show only when i upload my file.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional rendering:

```
     <div>
        <div className="peers fxw-nw pos-r">
          <div className="" id="main-window-scroll">
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.getMuiTheme()}>
              {tableEmpty ? <LoadingIndicator> : <MUIDataTable //use some kind of
                title={"FAQs Data List"}                       //loading indicator
                data={this.state.faqList}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
                // onRowClick={this.handleRowSelection}
              />}
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            {/* {this.loadDataTable()} */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: yup it worked but got an issue, the options parameter that I gave is not reflecting now.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a boolean value in state like isUploading.

When the upload starts, set isLoading to true, and when the upload finishes set isUploading to false.

And in your jsx, you can decide to show or hide your table checking this value.
For example:

```
{!this.state.isUploading && <MUIDataTable
                title={"FAQs Data List"}
                data={this.state.faqList}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
                // onRowClick={this.handleRowSelection}
              />
   }
```

Comment: yup, its working, but a weird issue came up, the options parameters are not reflecting for the table. any idea about it?